# How to import a stylesheet from external source in react?

Tags: css, reactjs

I mean icons from fontawesome or fonts from google fonts. In HTML i place something like this in the head:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
```

What about react?

Comment: you can place it in the head of `index.html` file

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can just import it in your style sheet like so

```
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto');
```

And your body style will become

```
body {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to import it inside js extension reactjs because I am not using any css file instance use material-ui css

Comment: You can add it as link to your index.html should work correctly

Answer (score 4):

inset the link in your index.html

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
```